# Is it required that an $f$ should be continuous on the interval $I$ to have an antiderivative $F$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $f: [a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is discontinuous only at a point $c\  \in[a,b]$. Now we can say that the integral $$\int_{[a,b]}f$$ exists since discontinuity occurs at a set with measure zero. But if for the antiderivative $F$ to exist, it is required that $f$ must be continuous on all points in the interval, how would you recommend me to find the integral?

Comment: Find an antiderivative for $[a,c)$ and other for $(c,b]$.

Comment: $f$ need not be continuous at all points, there are (everywhere) differentiable functions with discontinuous derivative.

Comment: Well if $f$ has a jump discontinuity at any point of the interval then it is guaranteed that $f$ can't have an anti derivative over the interval. A good case is when $f(x) =\cos(1/x), f(0)=0$ which is discontinuous at $x=0$ and yet possesses an anti-derivarive over whole of $\mathbb{R} $, but in this case the discontinuity is not a jump discontinuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find an antiderivative for $[a,c)$ and other for $(c,b]$:
$$\int_a^bf(t)dt=F_1(c)-F_1(a)+F_2(b)-F_2(c)$$

It is possible to find $F_1$ and $F_2$ such that $F_1(c)=F_2(c)$ to make this terms vanish in the latter equation, but you still have different functions for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

the antiderivative (i.e. the integral) is just measuring the area under the curve. So a discontinuous curve is not at all a problem for that.